# How to use generated id further in my code (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

i'm using javascript. In my code (given below) table is generated by holding input field in each cell, and ID is generated for each input field.

Actually I need to access the generated id_name to change the style (color,font-size,etc,...) for each input value.

```js
function myFunction() {

  //getting no. of cols and rows
  var cols = document.getElementById("id1").value;
  var rows = document.getElementById("id2").value;
  
  //table creation 
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var i,j,k=0;

  for(i=0;i<cols;i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    for(j=0;j<rows;j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');

      //generating input field for each cell 
      var input = document.createElement("input");
       input.type = "text";
       input.value = "";
       input.id=makeid(k+1);
       td.appendChild(input);

      var text = document.createTextNode(td.innerText);
      td.appendChild(text);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      table.appendChild(tr);
    
      document.body.appendChild(table);
      k++;
    }
  }  
}

//generating id_name (eg: A AA AAA AAAA ......)
function makeid(len) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       =         'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.len;
   for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}

function myFun() {

    //access id_name for changing style for each input value

}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="id1" value="" placeholder="col"  autocomplete="off">
<input type="number"  id="id2" onKeyup="myFunction()" value="" placeholder="row" autocomplete="off">

<button id='id3' onclick="myFun()" style='float:right;'>Change</button>
```

Eg: if you give values 2 and 2 for cols and rows, then 4 input field will be generated then type anything in that field and i want to apply style for that when clicking on the button 'change'

Comment: do you want to change the style for <td> data

Comment: @Rishab no for input value

Comment: input value for cols and rows?

Comment: if you give 2 and 2 for cols and rows then 4 input field will be generated then type anything in that field  and i want to apply style for that when clicking on change button

Comment: Hi I have added the answer for your query please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to iterate through the table rows and apply the style to the input field.

To change the style of an HTML element, use this syntax:

```
 document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style
```

```js
function myFun() {
  var table = document.getElementById('my_table');
  var tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
     // add style to input field
     tds[i].firstElementChild.style.color="red";
  }
}


function myFunction() {

  //getting no. of cols and rows
  var cols = document.getElementById("id1").value;
  var rows = document.getElementById("id2").value;
  
  //table creation 
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var i,j,k=0;
  table.setAttribute("id", "my_table");

  for(i=0;i<cols;i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(j=0;j<rows;j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');

      //generating input field for each cell 
      var input = document.createElement("input");
       input.type = "text";
       input.value = "";
       input.id=makeid(k+1);
       td.appendChild(input);

      var text = document.createTextNode(td.innerText);
      td.appendChild(text);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      table.appendChild(tr);
    
      document.body.appendChild(table);
      k++;
    }
  }  
}

//generating id_name (eg: A AA AAA AAAA ......)
function makeid(len) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       =         'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.len;
   for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="id1" value="" placeholder="col"  autocomplete="off">
<input type="number"  id="id2" onKeyup="myFunction()" value="" placeholder="row" autocomplete="off">

<button id='id3' onclick="myFun()" style='float:right;'>Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only wants to get input fields.

```
css 
  .test {
   color:green,
   font:12px;
 }


var dynamicInputs = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="A"]');

function classChanges(input){
    input.setAttribute('class','test')
}

dynamicInputs.forEach(classChanges);
```